# Why my dog can't open his eyes full?

Tags: dogs

I have a new born 6 week old puppy. He is fine with all aspects but he can't open his eyes full. Is it due to infection or by birth issue ? Please suggest me what should i do? Should i worry for this?

Comment: Can you tell us what breed your dog is? And a picture would help a lot. From your description alone it's hard to diagnose.

Comment: When is this happening? Is it when your puppy is waking up in the morning or after a nap? Have you asked the pup's breeder about it? Are the puppies eyes swollen? (How long have you had this puppy?) So many questions! More detail would help a lot. Thanks!

Comment: you need to give more information in your question.one good rule is if you are worried enough to ask a question then you should take it to a vet.